# how to avoid consecutive specials characters but allow new line to add in text area using regex

Tags: regex

Regex not allow to press enter key in text area while adding regex to all below characters

```
(?!\s)[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\'\,\-\;\:\(\)\[\]\\\/\@\#\!\*\$\%\^\|\?\s\r\n\&quot;\&amp;]{0,1000}
```

But don't want to allowed consecutive characters so added below regex which is blocking newline character also.

```
^(?!.*[\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\#\*\;\@\[\:\!\-]{2}).*$
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for.  Try this:  ^(?!\n.[\%/\\&\?\,\'#*\;\@[:!-]{2}).$

Answer (score 0):

In a regex, `.` doesn't match newline by default. If you want to match any character included newline, you have to change `.` to `[\s\S]`.

Your second regex becomes (I've removed the unecessary escapes):

```
^(?!.*[%/\\&?,'#*;@[:!-]{2})[\s\S]*$
```

But I guess to want to combine your two regexes:

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*[%/\\&?,'#*;@[:!-]{2})[-\w.',;:()[\]\\/@#!*$%^|?\s]{0,1000}$
```